# The Font Awesome child tags are too specific - are they even necessary?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[font-awesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/font-awesome) has two version-related tags which are used to differentiate between old and new syntax styles.

1. [font-awesome-3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/font-awesome-3.2) has 10 questions and presumably exists to handle the old syntax (as 3.2.1 was the latest version which used an `icon-` prefix).
2. [font-awesome-4.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/font-awesome-4.0.0) has 39 questions and, once again, presumably exists to handle the new syntax (as 4.0.0 was the version up from 3.2.1 which now uses a `fa-` prefix).

Unfortunately this tag system doesn't appear to be working anyway. 4.0.0 is incredibly specific; Font Awesome is now on version 4.3.0, which kinda makes the 4.0.0 tag redundant.

Unfortunately I can't suggest synonyms for either of these, but I feel that the [font-awesome-4.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/font-awesome-4.0.0) tag should be removed altogether or at the very least renamed to [font-awesome-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/font-awesome-4). Do we even need the [font-awesome-3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/font-awesome-3.2) tag? The main syntax difference is the class name `fa` instead of `icon` - meaning it'd be pretty obvious to anyone in most questions which version OP is discussing.

Comment: The difference isn't only the class prefix − there are a lot of new and/or renamed icon names and classes in Font Awesome 4. But I do agree that 4.0.0 is way too specific.

Comment: Is there anyone active in those tags who has the reputation to simply replace -4.0.0 with -4 without going through review queues?  It might be controversial for an outsider to do it, but if a tag expert things that is the right approach, can't see any drawback.  [Looks like there are at least 10 such users](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/font-awesome/topusers)

Answer (score 4):

- [font-awesome-3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/font-awesome-3.2) has been [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), after Léo's [argument](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293738/the-font-awesome-child-tags-are-too-specific-are-they-even-necessary#comment191040_293738) that there is a difference between version 3.2 and 4.
- [font-awesome-4.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/font-awesome-4.0.0) has been [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). I've renamed it to [font-awesome-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/font-awesome-4), as that's what the tag was being used for anyway.